# Web application to build on top of elasticsearch using node.js and express

Tags: node.js, express, elasticsearch

I am working on a project where I want to build a simple web application on top of elasticsearch using node.js and express. I am newbie to web frameworks. I didn't find any good resource to connect elasticsearch to express web framework. I have indexed  data in my elasticsearch. I want to build a simple web page that will allow user to search for a query and get back results from elasticsearch.

-I have read about how to connect mongo db with node.js and express.js, but I couldn't find any good resource to connect it with elasticsearch. I would appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: What about this one: https://blog.raananweber.com/2015/11/24/simple-autocomplete-with-elasticsearch-and-node-js/

Comment: @Val Thanks. I will check this post.